# Acer TravelMate 253M, battery not being charged

Tags: battery, acer-travelmate

I bought a new Acer TravelMate notebook 253M today. When the charger is connected with the laptop, it is on, or I can switch it on, but it always shows the battery is empty or cannot find the battery. Also, whenever I unplug the charger or take the charger's plug out of the notebook, the computer turns off.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the battery is dead.

If the notebook is brand new, then take it in under warranty and get the battery replaced.  If this was purchased used (assuming as such, since that notebook was released in 2012), then you'll probably have to go buy a new battery.

Comment: Oh no, that's bad news! But the laptop is brand new and new new, not used or refurbished.

One quick question though: can I take it to any computer repair shop and they will replace the battery for free? I bought the laptop from amazon.de and I'm not located inside Germany.

Comment: Why would any (likely unrelated to amazon) shop repair your computer for free? If you bought it from a shop then take (or ship) it back to that shop, or contact the manufacturer (depending on your country they must offer a certain warranty. Batteries are usually excluded because they can degrade quickly, but DOA is DOA and either the shop or the manufacturer should repair that.